# Can we detect when files begin to download in a Chrome Extension and can we access the local downloaded files?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm going to develop a Chrome Extension detecting status when files begin to download from chrome browser and read the files for certain purposes.

- Whenever files are downloaded on Chrome browser, is it available to detect it in the Chrome Extension?
- Can we access the downloaded files in local storage and read it in the Chrome Extension?
- Can we drag and drop a file from desktop to the tray icon of Chrome Extension?

Comment: [`chrome.downloads.onCreated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onCreated) for #1, and no for #2/#3. Or if you want, put the logic of #2/#3 in native application and use something like [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to transfer data.

Comment: Is that means if I make a native application and a chrome extension both would be possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

// 1. Store the download id.

let downloadId;

chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function (downloadItem) {
console.log("filename with absolute local path " , downloadItem.filename); // prints ""
// Just FYI, you won't get downloadItem.filename here. So store the downloadId
downloadId = downloadItem.id;
});

// 2. Get the filename by using following api. Use downloadId acquired from above step

chrome.downloads.search({id: downloadId}, function (downloadItem) {
console.log("filename with absolute local path " , downloadItem.filename);
// prints "C:/user/downloads/yourfile"
});

// Now use `<input type="file" >` in your `popup.html`
// and access the file which match with your filename acquired from step 2.

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that they will be called one after the another as both being asynchronous in nature.